# Large Memory (Data Size) Collection

Tags: java, data-structures, collections, bigdata

Very often I have to use objects from the java.util.collection package, objects that conform to the the Map and Set interfaces.

When I insert several million tuples or entities into these objects (HashMap, TreeMap, etc) their performance, both insertion and look-up slow to a crawl.

I have devised, derived classes which are essentially compositions of the classes in java.util.collection that scale better in performance.

I was wondering if there is an open source equivalent of the java.util.collections package that is optimized for handling large amounts of data.

Comment: Why would you create maps and sets with millions of elements in memory? Can't you use relational database with indexes?

Comment: @Maciej Ziarko, There would be numerous cases/benefits for storing millions of elements in RDBMS, NoSQL Dbs, however there are times when working with large objects in memory makes sense and is much preferred over the RDBMS, NoSQL DB approach. An responder has posted a project Trove that I think addresses this need. Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For better performing collections libraries, try [trove](http://trove.starlight-systems.com/). But, in general, you want to tackle these kinds of issues by streaming, or another form of lazy loading, such that you can do things like aggregation without loading the entire dataset into memory.

You could also use a key value store like Redis or CouchDB for storing this data.

Comment: Thanks for your response, 1+. Is trove free to use or must one purchase it first?

Comment: it's free, you can go to the link I included and download it.

Comment: Many thanks for the response @PaulSanwald, This is exactly what I was looking for -- though a user of Redis/CouchDB they're not what I had in mind but Trove seems to fit the bill. Would be interested in other similar projects.

Comment: Don't forget to write when it helps. I personally doubt.

Comment: Depends what usage patterns you expect.  Trove appears to use open-addressed tables, which are notably problematic when you need to do a lot of removals, or you do a lot of `contains` or `get` queries that turn out `false` or `null` respectively, or if you need to iterate over the entries of the collection.